# How to make case REMOVED fire when the last element is removed from Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to listen for real-time updates and I'm using the following code in `onEvent`:

```
override fun onEvent(querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, e: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
    if (e != null) return

    if (!querySnapshot!!.isEmpty) {
        for (change in querySnapshot.documentChanges) {
            value = when (documentChange.type) {
                Type.ADDED -> change.document.toObject<Item>(Item::class.java)
                Type.MODIFIED -> change.document.toObject<Item>(Item::class.java)
                Type.REMOVED -> vchange.document.toObject<Item>(Item::class.java)
            }
        }
    } else {
        logErrorMessage("querySnapshot.isEmpty")
    }
}
```

Let's assume we have 2 elements added in a collection. For each addition, case `Type.ADDED` is triggered. If I remove one of them, `Type.REMOVED` is triggered. The problem comes, when I try to remove the last item. Instead of having case `Type.REMOVED` triggered for the last time, I get an empty querySnapshot. So the `Type.REMOVED` case is **not** triggered anymore. How can I be notified when the last element is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that your code is only looking for document changes if the query results are not empty.  If the results become empty, you're just not checking to see if there was a change that made it empty.  Remove the check for `!querySnapshot!!.isEmpty` and just list each change regardless.

Answer (score 1):

If your `querySnapshot` **is empty** then you won't satisfy the if condition, therefore, you won't enter any of the cases on your `when` statement.

Also, since your snapshot is empty, there is **no data** to map to your `Item.class`